# Windows 10 virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper-win installed, virtualenv works fine, wrapper not so much

Tags: python, virtualenv

New to this malarky but trying to set up a virtual environment for django.

I have installed virtualenv and can use the virtualenv fine.  I have also installed virtualenvwrapper-win but I get 'command not found' when running any commands (such as mkvirtualenv).  They are both installed in the same folder and I can't find any posts which specifically address this issue.

```
bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found

$ pip show virtualenv
Name: virtualenv
Version: 20.0.16
Summary: Virtual Python Environment builder
Home-page: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/
Author: Bernat Gabor
Author-email: gaborjbernat@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: six, appdirs, distlib, filelock
Required-by: virtualenvwrapper-win
```

```
$ pip show virtualenvwrapper-win
Name: virtualenvwrapper-win
Version: 1.2.6
Summary: Port of Doug Hellmann's virtualenvwrapper to Windows batch scripts
Home-page: https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/
Author: David Marble
Author-email: davidmarble@gmail.com
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: c:\users\...\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Requires: virtualenv
Required-by:
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been going round in circles for some time.

Comment: `pip show --files virtualenvwrapper-win` and look where're scripts.

Comment: The scripts well under python38\scripts but it got me thinking and I tried mkvirtualenv.bat which worked.. so cheers!

Comment: @Jon beer for you fot pointing out that is .bat extension problem.